# Fill textarea with js

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, getelementsbyclassname

I don't understand why this doesn't  function :(

```html
<textarea class="js-compose-text compose-text txt-size--14 scroll-v scroll-styled-v scroll-styled-h scroll-alt padding-a--0" placeholder="What's happening?" style="height: 130px;"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("js-compose-text compose-text txt-size--14 scroll-v scroll-styled-v scroll-styled-h scroll-alt padding-a--0").value = "TESTESTTEST";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: getElementsByClassName finding array of objects, not one object

Answer (score 3):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object so you need to specify the exact element like `document.getElementsByClassName("js-compose-text compose-text txt-size--14 scroll-v scroll-styled-v scroll-styled-h scroll-alt padding-a--0")[0].value = "TESTESTTEST";`

```html
<textarea class="js-compose-text compose-text txt-size--14 scroll-v scroll-styled-v scroll-styled-h scroll-alt padding-a--0" placeholder="What's happening?" style="height: 130px;"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("js-compose-text compose-text txt-size--14 scroll-v scroll-styled-v scroll-styled-h scroll-alt padding-a--0")[0].value = "TESTESTTEST";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript multiple textarea's or div's can have the same class name but unique ID's. When you access any element by its id then it is unique and you can call it by its Id but when you access the element by name you, you have to access every element under the same class name by index as explained below -

```html
<textarea class="text" id="1"></textarea> //First textarea
<textarea class="text" id="2"></textarea> //Second textarea
<textarea class="text" id="3"></textarea> //Third textarea
<textarea class="text" id="4"></textarea> //Fourth textarea
```

To access 3 rd text area -

```html
document.getElementById("3");
//OR
document.getElementsByClassName("text")[2];
```

Both the code will do the same thing